# Agregar Vistas en RelativeLayout

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, activity

Que tal? Espero puedan ayudarme, deseo crear un LinearLayout y un ScrollView dentro de un RelativeLayout, tengo una idea pero la verdad no me queda, estoy algo confundido con respecto a las dimensiones MATCH_PARENT y WRAP_CONTENT, anexo una imagen para que visualicen mi idea, gracias por su atencion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El resultado que quieres obtener está claro, ahora puedes mostrar como has planteado el XML y decirnos ¿dónde te falla? o ¿qué es lo que llegas a obtener con tu código?

Answer (score 1):

match_parent -> El elemento ocupa el total de su elemento padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

wrap_content -> El elemento se expandirá solo lo suficiente para contener los valores/elementos que contiene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para obtener lo que deseas debes agregar el siguiente código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/color0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@color/color"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/llayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--elementos-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:background="@color/color1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:background="@color/color2"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <!--elementos-->
            <View
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="500dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Vas a obtener lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar que a tu primer `LinearLayout` le debes asignar un layout_height estatico `android:layout_height="200dp"` en este caso como ejemplo le puse `200dp` pero lo modificaras de acuerdo a tus necesidades. ademas de eliminar el elmento `View` en `ScroollView` > `LinearLayout` puesto solo fue para hacer notar la organizacion de los elementos.